# Clarification of definition of category

Tags: category-theory

Need the set of objects and the set of non-id morphisms be disjoint? If not, can the morphisms be a subset of the objects?

Comment: They are different things. Morphisms are *arrows* connecting two objects. A morphism is not an object.

Comment: You are not prohibited, by law, from hitting your thumb with a hammer, but I recommend against it.

Comment: The question isn't well-typed. It's like asking whether $\pi$ is an element of $3$. ZFC allows you to ask this question, but that's just a reason not to use ZFC. See http://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/the-type-system-of-mathematics/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the most direct (set theoretic) construction of $\mathbf{Set}$, the category of small sets, the objects are small sets, and the morphisms are set-theoretic functions. Because every function between small sets is itself a small set, the morphisms of $\mathbf{Set}$ are indeed a subclass of the objects of $\mathbf{Set}$.

Depending on your *precise* definition of category, you might instead need the morphisms to be triples $(A,f,B)$ where $A,B$ are sets and $f$ is a function whose domain is $A$ and whose range is a subset of $B$. But the usual set-theoretic definition of triples make these into small sets, so we still get the same result.

Comment: A good example of a category which does not have the required property in practice!

Answer (score 5):

Disjointness is a red herring: there is never a situation where objects and morphisms are considered on equal grounds. However, it is often convenient to assume that the two are disjoint.

There is always an injection of the set of objects into the set of morphisms, namely the map $x \mapsto \mathrm{id}_x$, so the cardinality of the set of morphisms is always at least the cardinality of the set of objects.

Comment: Of course, as in other remarks here, the collection of all objects need not be a "set", although typically the collection of morphisms from one object to another is "required" to be a "set".

Answer (score 4):

First of all, neither the objects nor the morphisms are required to be a set, they can be any class, even a proper one. Second, the definition does not forbid the morphisms to be a subclass of the objects. I can't think of any non-artificial example, though.

Comment: The silly example is a category in which the only morphisms are each object's identity morphism. Then the class of objects and the class of morphisms can be naturally identified. But, indeed, this doesn't do anything non-trivial or interesting...

Comment: Artificial, objects A B C f n, non-id morphisms f:A->B n:f->C. Does this satisfy the definition of a category?

Comment: An example is to take the category whose objects are matrices with full column rank, and $\hom(A,B)$ is the set of matrices $M$ such that the columns of $MA$ are in the columnspace of $B$. This isn't as silly as it sounds -- in actual computation, one often represents a vector space by writing a matrix and decreeing the vector space is the columnspace of that matrix, so in this category, I've used the actual representation as the objects, rather than the abstract notion being represented. (also, the category I've stated is an example where the homsets are not disjoint!)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one situation in which you *might* care is if you want to think of a functor $f:C\to D$ as a monolithic function that maps $C$-data to $D$-data. Then you would want the set of $C$-data to be a disjoint union of the object set of $C$ and all its homsets. But I don't know anyone actually takes this viewpoint. (And as paul garrett  points out, for non-small categories, these need not be sets.)

Comment: However, in terms of _notation_ that is what we do all the time...

Comment: @ZhenLin That's a great point! Still, formalizing it as such seems... odd somehow.